# How to programatically find out whether the application is using sencha-touch or extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here I'm implementing a sample.js file in which designing a floating component.
This sample.js file is independent of any other application. It means when i'm adding this file to sencha-touch project it should show the floating component and if i'm adding this sample.js to ext4.1 project then also it should show the component.

For this i want to know whether the application is using Sencha touch sdk or ext 4.1 sdk?

How can i achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can know whether it's touch or extjs by executing the following condition

```
if( Ext.versions.touch ){
    //write your touch related code here
}else if( Ext.versions.extjs ){
    //write your extjs code here
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. But it is not documented nor can it be found in the source code. So can I rely on this?

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.version` is documented for Sencha Touch, `Ext.versions` is not. Alternative to url solution will be:

```
if(window.Ext) {
   if(Ext.version) {
      // Touch
   }
   else {
      // Extjs
   }
}
```